# The snow problem - error at store a variable

Tags: python

I am learning algorithms and I'm been stuck on my while loop.

The Problem is: Given an array of wall heights, calculate the snow that can be stored inbetween them. [image: problem image]

the black bricks represents walls, blue briks represent the snow and the array that we see below is the height of every wall.

One of my solution is a cuadratic function that make 2 loops to calculate how many snow we store. So here is my code:

```
walls = (0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2)

def snow_stored_cuadratic(walls):
    snow_stored = 0
    max_height = max(walls)

    print(max_height)
        
    while (max_height > 0):
        find_wall = False
        brick = 0
        for wall in walls:
            value = wall
            if value >= max_height:
                find_wall = True
                snow_stored += brick 
                brick = 0
                continue
            if find_wall:
                brick += 1
         max_height -= max_height
            
    return snow_stored
```

When I run my code, the result is 0 but they need to return 12. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What good is your while loop for? You only ever touch `max_height` once, and then you reduce it to 0 - Your while loop will only ever be run once through...

Comment: You have: `value = wall ; if value >= wall:` The if will always be `True`. Did you mean that?

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes it was that I make a mistake at max_height -= max_height when I want to write max_height -= -1 thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error was at the end of the while loop statement. I want to decrease by 1 and I felt doin max_height -= max_height

The solution is:

```
walls = (0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2)

def snow_stored_cuadratic(walls):
    snow_stored = 0
    max_height = max(walls)
    
    print(max_height)
            
    while (max_height > 0):
        find_wall = False
        brick = 0
        for wall in walls:
            value = wall
            if value >= max_height:
                find_wall = True
                snow_stored += brick 
                brick = 0
                continue
            if find_wall:
                brick += 1
        max_height -= 1
                
    return snow_stored
```